# HttpServerFilter for path with required variable

Tags: micronaut

So I can't get this HttpServerFilter to work for a path containing a variable (and only if the variable is present).

The filter should not match on path `/cars` or `/cars/` but only when requesting a single entity, such as `/cars/123` or `/cars/456`

`@Filter("/cars/**")` will off course match on both, `@Filter("/cars/{id}")` will only match on the exact path `"/cars/{id}"` and not for any variable.

Comment: Did you intend for `/files/` to be `/cars/`?

Comment: Ah yes, I was supposed to change the example from files to cars but yes, it's supposed to be the same path.

Answer (score 0):

`@Filter("/files/*")` will do what you want. You can't use variables in filters since it just uses ant path matching

Comment: I changed my question to use `cars`, but point still stands. While a request to `/cars` isn't filtered, a trailing slash (which to be fair should be treated as another path)  `/cars/` is. I would like them to be treated as the same path though which shouldn't be filtered. But this might be good enough.